# Json get not working through azure but working locally

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have created a asp.net webapi and hosted it through azure. 
This works fine when I run `host/api/carparks`. It also works when I run an ODATA query string

`host/api/carparks?$Filter%20eq%20%27Liverpool%27`

Google chrome returns the results as JSON as I want them.

[image: Working JSON get example with Azure]

The problem I am having is, I need to create a "Client" application to visualize my data. I have created a really simple for loop to return my data for testing purposes, once I have data returned I can start creating my application.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getStations() {

        var town = document.getElementById("town").value;

        var stationList = "<p>";

        var uri = "http://localhost:38852/api/carparks?$filter=Town%20eq%20%27" + town + "%27";
        $.getJSON(uri,
             function (data) {
                 $('#here_data').empty(); // Clear existing text.
                 // Loop through the list of products.
                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                     stationList += val.Name + '<br />';

                 });
                 stationList += "</p>";
                 document.getElementById("here_data").innerHTML =     stationList;
            });
     }
     $(document).ready(getStations);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getStations()">
<h1>Stations API</h1>
<p>Enter town</p>
<input type="text" id="town" value="Derby" />
<input type="button" value="Find Stations" onclick="getStations()" />
<div id="here_data">
<p>Car parks go here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My client app works perfectly when I run my web api locally but when I change the getJSON request URI to my azure one (Which works in the browser!) nothing happens.

[image: Working 'Client side' locally.]

I have tried uploading my client app to azure and testing it that way but nothing :(

Is there any Azure settings that need to be changed?

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Does your function run? Can you see an HTTP Request in your browser's networking tools? Can you see an error in your browser's JavaScript console? What happens if you add a `.fail` on there as [described in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)? Is the URL correct in your Azure hosted code, including the port?

Comment: @mason Thanks for your reply. The function does run but it doesn't return any data. I tried to include another image showing what happens but it wont allow me because I'm a stack overflow n00b. I have just uploaded the 'client side' html page onto my web api and it is working as I want it too. However it isn't working from a separate web application.

Comment: You really didn't answer much of what I asked in my previous comment. Please re-read it and make sure you address everything.

Comment: @mason Hi sorry, does this help? http://imgur.com/kq1xcX6 The URL is correct in the azure code.

Comment: HTTP 304 is a [not modified](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very much like a cross-origin issue.

The issue does not occur when you call the Service directly in your browser but only when you issue an Ajax call from a different domain (localhost vs. *.azurewebsites.net).

If you want to access your Web Api service with an Ajax call from a different domain you need to enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

A detailed article is found here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Quoted from the link:

> ```
> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
> ```
>
> Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the
>   **`WebApiConfig.Register`** method.
>
> ```
> public static class WebApiConfig
> {
>     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
>     {
>         // New code
>         config.EnableCors();
>
>         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
>             name: "DefaultApi",
>             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
>             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Next, add the **[EnableCors]** attribute to the `TestController` class:
>
> using System.Net.Http; using System.Web.Http; using
>   System.Web.Http.Cors;
>
> ```
> namespace WebService.Controllers
> {
>     [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
>     public class TestController : ApiController
>     {
>         // Controller methods not shown...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> For the origins parameter, use the URI where you deployed the
>   WebClient application. This allows cross-origin requests from
>   WebClient, while still disallowing all other cross-domain requests.
>   Later, I’ll describe the parameters for [EnableCors] in more detail.
>
> Do not include a forward slash at the end of the origins URL.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll make sure I try this when I'm near my PC and let you know.

Comment: You can set the CORS options via the Azure Portal - CORS is on the Settings blade.

Comment: @viperguynaz thanks, I have changed this option in azure portal. It hasn't fixed the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @florian-lim I'm trying your method but what do you mean about the Testing Controller? Sorry, I'm new to this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @viperguynaz and @florian I have fixed my issue. I changed the CORS option in Azure portal. (When I first did it I didn't remove the forward slash at the end of the URL). I removed the slash and it works.

I have also used the info given by @florian to help me understand CORS more.

Thanks again
1 happy joe :)

Comment: This answer really helped me, as I was deploying a node.JS app, where I allowed the cross-domain in my app, but it was not enough. I also had to go through the Azure Portal and set it there. It's like a double safety, which I find quite weird; These kind of check should be done at the application level, shouldn't they ?